# How can I parse this api json with flutter?

Tags: json, api, http, flutter, dart

I am pretty new to coding.  I finished all of the UI of an app for myself but I cannot figure out how to input the data from an api into my app.

I have been trying for over a week.  Read so many articles and videos but this api never works.  I have come to the conclusion that I am doing something wrong with the fetching part.  Maybe because everything I read or watch demonstrates with a List instead of a Map.

Here is a copy of my code.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Future<Stock> futureStock;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureStock = fetchStock();
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Material App Bar'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<Stock>(
            future: futureStock,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text(snapshot.data.companyName);
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text("${snapshot.error}");
              }
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Future<Stock> fetchStock() async {
  final response = await http.get(
      'https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/stock/aapl/stats?token=Tsk_38ddda0b877a4510b42a37ae713cdc96');
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return Stock.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  } else {
    throw Exception('Fail to load');
  }
}

Stock stockFromJson(String str) => Stock.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String stockToJson(Stock data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Stock {
  Stock({
    this.week52Change,
    this.week52High,
    this.week52Low,
    this.marketcap,
    this.employees,
    this.day200MovingAvg,
    this.day50MovingAvg,
    this.float,
    this.avg10Volume,
    this.avg30Volume,
    this.ttmEps,
    this.ttmDividendRate,
    this.companyName,
    this.sharesOutstanding,
    this.maxChangePercent,
    this.year5ChangePercent,
    this.year2ChangePercent,
    this.year1ChangePercent,
    this.ytdChangePercent,
    this.month6ChangePercent,
    this.month3ChangePercent,
    this.month1ChangePercent,
    this.day30ChangePercent,
    this.day5ChangePercent,
    this.nextDividendDate,
    this.dividendYield,
    this.nextEarningsDate,
    this.exDividendDate,
    this.peRatio,
    this.beta,
  });

  double week52Change;
  double week52High;
  double week52Low;
  int marketcap;
  int employees;
  double day200MovingAvg;
  double day50MovingAvg;
  int float;
  double avg10Volume;
  double avg30Volume;
  double ttmEps;
  double ttmDividendRate;
  String companyName;
  int sharesOutstanding;
  double maxChangePercent;
  double year5ChangePercent;
  double year2ChangePercent;
  double year1ChangePercent;
  double ytdChangePercent;
  double month6ChangePercent;
  double month3ChangePercent;
  double month1ChangePercent;
  double day30ChangePercent;
  double day5ChangePercent;
  dynamic nextDividendDate;
  double dividendYield;
  DateTime nextEarningsDate;
  DateTime exDividendDate;
  double peRatio;
  double beta;

  factory Stock.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Stock(
        week52Change: json["week52change"].toDouble(),
        week52High: json["week52high"].toDouble(),
        week52Low: json["week52low"].toDouble(),
        marketcap: json["marketcap"],
        employees: json["employees"],
        day200MovingAvg: json["day200MovingAvg"].toDouble(),
        day50MovingAvg: json["day50MovingAvg"].toDouble(),
        float: json["float"],
        avg10Volume: json["avg10Volume"].toDouble(),
        avg30Volume: json["avg30Volume"].toDouble(),
        ttmEps: json["ttmEPS"].toDouble(),
        ttmDividendRate: json["ttmDividendRate"].toDouble(),
        companyName: json["companyName"],
        sharesOutstanding: json["sharesOutstanding"],
        maxChangePercent: json["maxChangePercent"].toDouble(),
        year5ChangePercent: json["year5ChangePercent"].toDouble(),
        year2ChangePercent: json["year2ChangePercent"].toDouble(),
        year1ChangePercent: json["year1ChangePercent"].toDouble(),
        ytdChangePercent: json["ytdChangePercent"].toDouble(),
        month6ChangePercent: json["month6ChangePercent"].toDouble(),
        month3ChangePercent: json["month3ChangePercent"].toDouble(),
        month1ChangePercent: json["month1ChangePercent"].toDouble(),
        day30ChangePercent: json["day30ChangePercent"].toDouble(),
        day5ChangePercent: json["day5ChangePercent"].toDouble(),
        nextDividendDate: json["nextDividendDate"],
        dividendYield: json["dividendYield"].toDouble(),
        nextEarningsDate: DateTime.parse(json["nextEarningsDate"]),
        exDividendDate: DateTime.parse(json["exDividendDate"]),
        peRatio: json["peRatio"].toDouble(),
        beta: json["beta"].toDouble(),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "week52change": week52Change,
        "week52high": week52High,
        "week52low": week52Low,
        "marketcap": marketcap,
        "employees": employees,
        "day200MovingAvg": day200MovingAvg,
        "day50MovingAvg": day50MovingAvg,
        "float": float,
        "avg10Volume": avg10Volume,
        "avg30Volume": avg30Volume,
        "ttmEPS": ttmEps,
        "ttmDividendRate": ttmDividendRate,
        "companyName": companyName,
        "sharesOutstanding": sharesOutstanding,
        "maxChangePercent": maxChangePercent,
        "year5ChangePercent": year5ChangePercent,
        "year2ChangePercent": year2ChangePercent,
        "year1ChangePercent": year1ChangePercent,
        "ytdChangePercent": ytdChangePercent,
        "month6ChangePercent": month6ChangePercent,
        "month3ChangePercent": month3ChangePercent,
        "month1ChangePercent": month1ChangePercent,
        "day30ChangePercent": day30ChangePercent,
        "day5ChangePercent": day5ChangePercent,
        "nextDividendDate": nextDividendDate,
        "dividendYield": dividendYield,
        "nextEarningsDate":
            "${nextEarningsDate.year.toString().padLeft(4, '0')}-${nextEarningsDate.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${nextEarningsDate.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}",
        "exDividendDate":
            "${exDividendDate.year.toString().padLeft(4, '0')}-${exDividendDate.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${exDividendDate.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}",
        "peRatio": peRatio,
        "beta": beta,
      };
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
I followed the official example from https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

Comment: What's the issue? Any errors? What behavior are you not achieving that you want? The json parsing seems fine from a glance.

Comment: What problem do you have ? Your code works. I run your code and on the screen I saw text with apple inc

Comment: Lol.  Crazy, my simulator must have been hanging.  I was just getting the circular indicator but after restarting it works.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested your code and can confirm it is working fine.

But if you are running the release build of your app, you need to add the following line into your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`